# Log4j2 Properties clear top part logs automatically when hit more than 100 MB

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am using log4j2 in spring boot. would like to know every time i restart the program, all the logs are cleared. I want the logs not all to be cleared unless if it is 100 MB of size, then the top part of the logs to be automatically cleared until the size is less than or equal to 100 MB.

```
status = debug
name = PropertiesConfig

#Make sure to change log file path as per your need
property.logPath = C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\log\\

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${logPath}app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies


appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

#Make sure to change the package structure as per your application

logger.rolling.name = com.jason
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file pattern says you will roll over the file every second or when a file reaches 100MB and you will keep a maximum of 20 files per second.

That kind of seems at odds with asking to only keep a total of 100MB of files but to do what you are asking you would need to add a Delete action to the DefaultRolloverStrategy. Something like

```
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${logPath}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxdepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.exceeds = 100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = debug-backup-*.log.gz
```

This will keep the newest log files until 100MB of space is used by files matching the pattern.

Comment: do you have references where i can study more on the log4j2.properties?

Comment: i use appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.exceeds

and removed

##appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
##appender.rolling.policies.size.size=2KB


not working

Comment: Remember that the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy will trigger a rollover when the file size is exceeded while the delete action will delete files when a rollover takes place. So you would use the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy to limit the size of the individual files.  Feel free to update the configuration with what you have that isn't working so I can look at the full configuration.

Comment: Also, you could try getting what you want working with XML and then translating that to properties. You may have more luck finding an XML configuration example that does what you want.

Comment: @rogers thanks will try it. Ok i got add SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy and remvoed #appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.exceeds. Can i know it is working, then why you addeded #appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.exceeds. Is there any specific reason? as with this scenario it is working

Comment: Unless I am misreading, your original requirement was to have no more than 100MB worth of log data on disk. If you are doing that through by having a single file that can be up to 100MB you would have to delete that file as soon as the rollover occurs to meet that.  If you make each file a max of 10 MB then you need the Delete action to delete files to make sure you don't exceed 100MB.

Comment: I want each file to have maximum of 100MB. Lets say we put 3KB for instance. Maximum file should be 3KB. so when the size hit 4KB, it should delete the top part of code until the size hit 3KB. This possible? As currently, when hit 4KB, it delete all the log and put 1KB

Comment: What you are asking isn't clear. You want each file to have a maximum of 100MB. OK the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy will cause a rollover when the file hits 100MB. But I don't understand what it means that each file should have a maximum of 100MB and a maximum of 3KB. How can it be both?  I also don't know what it means to delete the "top part of the code". I can't imagine that you really mean that as it would imply you are deleting your program as it is running. Do you mean the oldest entries in the file?

Comment: Hi the 3KB is example. Instead of using100MB i change it to 3KB so easier to explain. I will use 100MB now since got confusion. Yup i want delete while my program running and not delete all but delete oldest entries in the file up to 100MB. As currently it deleting entire log when rollover. I only want delete the oldest entry log and after delete the oldest entry log and the file size reach 100MB, there should not be any action done unless it reach more than 100MB, it should start deleting the oldest entry again until file size reach 100MB

Comment: OK. I know of no appender that works like that, either in Log4j or elsewhere.

Comment: To be clear what you are asking for is NOT a rolling file appender. You want an appender that logs to a single file and only keeps either the newest n events or the newest events while limiting the file to a fixed size.

Comment: yup correct this what i looking. is there any you can suggest?

Comment: Log4J does not have an appender like that and I am not aware of one developed elsewhere. Implementing it isn’t trivial and could have performance problems unless you use memory mapped files.